# Trying to Understand Angular Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand this code.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html

At line 44 we have something like

search = (text$: Observable) =>

When i hover over the search ,
Intellisense is telling me (property) of NgbdTypeaheadHttp.search

I am not getting it what is a property and why is it of type NgbdTypeaheadHttp.search.

Also my second question is this line
search = (text$: Observable)

So search is accepting a parameter called text$ ?

if so where is the parameter actually supplied ?

In the template i only see [ngbTypeahead]="search" but there is no parameter that is being supplied to search

Comment: You're stackblitz doesn't work.

Comment: Apologies i edited the stackbiltz link now

Comment: It doesn't work yet.

Comment: This is the stackblitz link OP is referring to: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stackblitz link is broken. I'm assuming you're referring to [this one](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html)

It seems you aren't quite aware of JS syntax and features. I suggest reading up.

1. `search` is a property of the class `NgbdTypeaheadHttp`, so obviously Intellisense would tell you the same thing
2. `search` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which accepts an `Observable` parameter
   `[ngbTypeahead]` in an input that accepts an arrow function with the same signature. This input is defined in `NgbModule`, which is part of the `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` package

Comment: Thanks I have corrected the link for some strange reason copy pasting doesn't seem to work.Can you also let me know where the search function is called and what is the value of the text$ observable ?

Comment: The `text$` observable will be a basic observable that emits a string value, which should be equal to the what you typed into the textbox.
It's registered as an output in the library somewhere. Don't worry about that